# Windows Power Shell rename files

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am sort of new to scripting and here's my task:

A folder with X files. Each file contains some Word documents, Excel sheets, etc. In these files, there is a client name and I need to assign an ID number.

This change will affect all the files in this folder that contain this client's name.

How can do this using Windows Power Shell?

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.config -rec
 foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace " JOHN ", "123" } |
Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Is this  the right approach ?

Comment: you are going to have to do things differently. [*grin*] PoSh cannot _directly_ edit word docs or excel spreadsheets. you can install a PoSh module to handle the spreadsheets [i think ImportExcel is the name of one such]. to edit the MSWord docs will require using COM to open MSWord and control it. look up using COM objects with powershell. ///// as an aside, the `PSPath` parameter is not the one that is usually recommended for what you are doing. instead use the `.FullName` property.

Comment: Do you want to *rename* files, or do you want to modify the *content* of files? Those are two entirely different operations.

Comment: Word and Excel documents are stored in a proprietary XML type format.  You really can't edit the contents of these documents with powershell.  Take a look at MS Office Interop.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers modify the content. Example : change a person name for a number in all of the files that have this persons name

Comment: If you want to modify the content of files the way to do that depends on the file type as Lee_Dailey already pointed out. Not all files are plaintext files (MS Office files specifically aren't).

Answer (score 1):

As @lee_Daily pointed out you would need to have different code to perform a find and replace in different file types. Here is an example of how you could go about doing that:

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $false

foreach ( $file in (Get-ChildItem . -r ) ) {
    Switch ( $file.Extension ) {
        ".config" {
            (Get-Content $file.FullName) |
                Foreach-Object { $_ -replace " JOHN ", "123" } |
                    Set-Content $file.FullName
        }
        {('.doc') -or ('.docx')} {
            ### Replace in word document using $file.fullname as the target
        }
        {'.xlsx'} {
            ### Replace in spreadsheet using $file.fullname as the target
        }
    }
}
```

For the actual code to perform the find and replace, i would suggest com objects for both.

**Example of word find and replace** https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174455/powershell-script-to-find-and-replace-in-word-document-including-header-footer

**Example of excel find and replace** [Search & Replace in Excel without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282052/search-replace-in-excel-without-looping)

I would suggest learning the ImportExcel module too, it is a great tool which i use a lot.

Comment: Where would you include the folder path ?

Comment: `(Get-ChildItem . -r )` the . is the current folder, i just used your example. Just change it to what you want.

Comment: Should I stick with Windows power shell or maybe try to implement into a C# language ?

Answer (score 0):

For Word Document : This is what I'm using.  Just can't figure out how this script could also change Header and Footer in a Word Document

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $false

$list = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\*.*" -Include *.doc*  
foreach($item in $list){
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($item.FullName,$true)

$objSelection = $objWord.Selection 
$wdFindContinue = 1
$FindText = " BLAH " 
$MatchCase = $False 
$MatchWholeWord = $true
$MatchWildcards = $False 
$MatchSoundsLike = $False 
$MatchAllWordForms = $False 
$Forward = $True 
$Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
$Format = $False 
$wdReplaceNone = 0 
$ReplaceWith = "help " 
$wdFindContinue = 1 
$ReplaceAll = 2

$a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ` 
$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$ReplaceAll) 
$objDoc.Save()
$objDoc.Close()
}
$objWord.Quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

What If I try to run on  C# ? Is anything else missing?

```
 }
string rootfolder = @"C:\Temp";
   string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rootfolder, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
   foreach (string file in files)
   {    try
     {    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
       contents = contents.Replace(@"Text to find", @"Replacement text");
       // Make files writable
   File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);

   File.WriteAllText(file, contents);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Switching to a different programming language doesn't magically allow you to treat binary files as text files.

Comment: I understand that but what you think would be the best approach

Comment: PowerShell is more than Ok for this, and i believe PowerShell and C# use the same method for office integration. Could be wrong, dont know C#.

Comment: @OwainEsau . I'm using powershell at the moment , I was able to find and figure out for Word Documents, but it does not change the file name and Header nd Footer of the file